# Organize functions that create or expand a text file using a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, text-files

I'm brand new to classes and I don't really know when to use them. I want to write a program for simulation of EPR/NMR spectra which requires information about the simulated system. The relevant thing is this: I have a function called `rel_inty(I_n,N)` that calculates this relevant information from two values. The problem is that it becomes very slow when either of these values becomes large (`I_n,N >= 10`). That's why I opted for calculating `rel_inty(I_n,N)` beforehand for the most relevant combinations of (`I_n,N`) and save them in a dictionary. I write that dictionary to a file and can import it using `eval()`, since calculating `rel_inty(I_n,N)` dynamically on each execution would be way too slow.

Now I had the following idea: What if I create a `class manage_Dict():`, whose methods can either recreate a basic dictionary with a`def basic():` , in case the old file somehow gets deleted, or expand the existing one with a `def expand():` method, if the basic one doesn't contain a user specified combination of (`I_n,N`)?

This would be the outline of that class:

```py
class manage_Dict(args):

    def rel_inty(I_n,N):
        '''calculates relative intensities for a combination (I_n,N)'''

    def basic():
        '''creates a dict for preset combinations of I_n,N'''

        with open('SpinSys.txt','w') as outf:

            Dict = {}
            I_n_List = [somevalues]
            N_List = [somevalues]

            for I_n in I_n_List:
                Dict[I_n] = {}
                for N in N_List:
                    Dict[I_n][N] = rel_inty(I_n,N)

            outf.write(str(Dict))

    def expand(*args):
        '''expands the existing dict for all tuples (I_n,N) in *args'''

        with open('SpinSys.txt','r') as outf:

            Dict = eval(outf.read())

            for tup in args:
                I_n = tup[0]
                N = tup[1]

                Dict[I_n][N] = rel_inty(I_n,N)

         os.remove('SpinSys.txt')

         with open('SpinSys.txt','w') as outf:

             outf.write(str(Dict))
```

Usage:

```py
'''Recreate SpinSys.txt if lost'''
manage_Dict.basic()

'''Expand SpinSys.txt in case of missing (I_n,N)'''
manage_Dict.expand((10,5),(11,3),(2,30))
```

Would this be a sensible solution? I was wondering that because I usually see classes with `self` and `__init__` creating an object instance instead of just managing function calls.

Comment: No, this is not how you should be using a class. There is no internal state, so it might as well just be a module with a bunch of module-level functions. Your class isn't actually doing anything, just holding a bunch of functions.

Comment: Should I just use nested functions? Is that what I'm looking for?

Comment: You are also missing `self` variable within your methods.

Comment: @J.Doe no, why would you nest the functions? Again, just a regular module with functions in it would make more sense than what you are doing.

Comment: @joumaico well actually, since the OP isn't creating instances, then you don't *have* to, and it would fail if the OP tried to do what they are doing.

Comment: Ohhhh so I just make a new .py file and define every function seperately. manage_dict.py with basic(), rel_inty() and expand() in it? I just really wanted to get some practice with classes becaus I never use them.

Comment: @J.Doe If you want to collect your functions inside a class without dealing with `self` then you can wrap/decorate them with `@staticmethod`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are going to make use of an object, lets make sure it's doing some useful work for us and the interface is nicer than just using functions. I'm going to suggest a few big tweaks that will make life easier:

- We can sub class `dict` itself, and then our object is a dict, as well as all our custom fancy stuff
- Use [JSON](https://json.org/) instead of text files, so we can quickly, naturally and safely serialise and deserialise

```py
import json


class SpectraDict(dict):
    PRE_CALC_I_N = ["...somevalues..."]
    PRE_CACL_N = ["...somevalues..."]

    def rel_inty(self, i_n, n):
        # Calculate and store results from the main function
        if i_n not in self:
            self[i_n] = {}

        if n not in self[i_n]:
            self[i_n][n] = self._calculate_rel_inty(i_n, n)

        return self[i_n][n]

    def _calculate_rel_inty(self, i_n, n):
        # Some exciting calculation here instead...
        return 0

    def pre_calculate(self):
        s_dict = SpectraDict()

        for i_n in self.PRE_CALC_I_N:
            for n in self.PRE_CACL_N:
                # Force the dict to calculate and store the values
                s_dict.rel_inty(i_n, n)

        return s_dict

    @classmethod
    def load(cls, json_file):
        with open(json_file) as fh:
            return SpectraDict(json.load(fh))

    def save(self, json_file):
        with open(json_file, 'w') as fh:
            json.dump(self, fh)

        return self
```

Now when ask for values using the `rel_inty()` function we immediately store the answer in ourselves before giving it back. This is called memoization / caching. Therefore to pre-fill our object with the pre-calculated values, we just need to ask it for lots of answers and it will store them.

After that we can either load or save quite naturally using JSON:

```py
# Bootstrapping from scratch:
s_dict = SpectraDict().pre_calculate().save('spin_sys.json')

# Loading and updating with new values
s_dict = SpectraDict.load('spin_sys.json')
s_dict.rel_inty(10, 45)  # All your new calculations here...
s_dict.save('spin_sys.json')
```

Comment: This is too hard to understand for a beginner.

Comment: You might be right, but I suppose it could be of use to others, or give a good puzzle to think over. Also a working example could provide something to work towards, even if it's not totally obvious right away.

Comment: No thanks, this is great. There is so much variety to classes that I didn't even know where to start after going over loads of isolated information. Seeing an example for something that I want to do kinda helped me connect a lot of the dots I think. It's still loads to take in, but I'm definetly getting the gist of it. So json.dump() is a really convenient function I see :D